# Append text not working in jquery, but document.write is?

Tags: jquery, html, append

I'm trying to append text to a div in javascript but nothing is showing up. My code is

```
$roundDoc .=    "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script type'text/javascript'>
                    var ifeed = $('.itemFeedText');
                    ifeed.append('$message');           
                </script>";
```

When I change ifeed.append to document.write() the data contained in $message is outputted onto the site. I have no errors in my js console. The div with class itemFeedText comes up in inspect element but it doesnt have the data in it. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: why are you using .=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is all messed up but my guess is you are missing document.ready function here (since it works with document.write). I recommend to seperate php or whatever language you are using with javascript.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type'text/javascript'>
    $(function(){ //donot forget to call document.ready function to make sure document is ready before executing javascrit
       var ifeed = $('.itemFeedText');
       ifeed.append('<?php echo $message ?>');           
   });
</script>
```

even better if you can seperate out $message from the above script and get it thourgh ajax or something.

Using your "not so clear" method. :):)

```
  $roundDoc .=    "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script type'text/javascript'>
                $(function(){
                var ifeed = $('.itemFeedText');
                ifeed.append('$message');
               });           
            </script>";
```